# Assign value to C# enum from C++/CLI const

Tags: c#, enums, c++-cli, constants, mixed-mode

I've searched through the other answers similar to this topic, but haven't found anything completely relevant.  I'm trying to assign values to some enumerations in C#, using values that are marked as static const in a C++/CLI file, which are compiled into a DLL and referenced in the C# project.  All of that works fine, except that it gives me the "The expression being assigned to 'XXX' must be constant", which I would expect, if the C++/CLI value wasn't a constant.  My C++/CLI code is auto-generated from 3rd-party vendor provided files, so my options for changing that side are extremely limited.

Here's some excerpts:

The C++/CLI file:

```
public ref class SEVERE_LEVEL sealed {
  public: 
    static const System::Int32 VALUE = 200;
  private:
    SEVERE_LEVEL() {}
};
```

And the C# file:

```
public enum LoggerLevel {
  SevereLevel = SEVERE_LEVEL.VALUE  // This gives the "must be constant" error
}
```

There are several different log levels, each defined in their own separate class in the C++/CLI file.  I want to use the C# enum as a parameter type in some method calls to ensure only valid values are passed in.  Any ideas how to make this work or suggestions on alternative designs?

Comment: That's a pretty quirky code generator.  I'd just try to jam in a `public enum class` declaration, like it should have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ `const` keyword doesn't map into anything in .NET.

C++/CLI adds new context-sensitive keywords to match the .NET functionality: `initonly` and `literal`.

If you use `literal System::Int32 VALUE = 200;` then it should work.  There's no magic to make the C# compiler define enums using values that aren't marked "literal" in the .NET metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I wrapped the auto-generated classes in a new C++ class containing members marked with the "literal" keyword set equal to the previous static const members.  This allows me to assign them to enums in C# perfectly fine.  Thanks!